# python pandas pivot table of numerical range from dataframe

Tags: python, range, pivot-table

Hello i would like to make a pivot table out of a dataframe that list out the companies according to their number of uploads on a website. Here is what I have:

df

```
Company        Uploads
Nike              11
Adidas            26
Apple             55
Tesla             3
Amazon            97
Ralph Lauren      54
Tiffany           19
Walmart           77
Target            18
Facebook          48
Google            81
```

Desired output

```
Range            Company        Uploads
>10              Tesla             3
11-50            Adidas            26
                 Tiffany           19
                 Target            18
                 Nike              11
51-100           Amazon            97
                 Google            81
                 Walmart           77
                 Apple             55
                 Ralph Lauren      54
```

I'm thinking adding a 'Range' column in df using np.where. Then make a pivot table using pd.pivot_table or .groupby. Then .sort_value for the descending upload number in the pivot table.

I'm not very sure if this would work. Can anyone please help me on this please? I appreciate any assistance. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.cut()`, which has the capability of binning, to classify a segment and use the name output by a label.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Company Uploads
Nike 11
Adidas 26
Apple 55
Tesla 3
Amazon 97
"Ralph Lauren" 54
Tiffany 19
Walmart 77
Target 18
Facebook 48
Google 81
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
df['category'] = pd.cut(df['Uploads'], [0,10,50,100], labels=['>10','11-50','51-100'])
df.sort_values(['category','Uploads'], ascending=[True, True], inplace=True)
df.set_index(['category','Company'],inplace=True)
df

Uploads
category    Company 
>10     Tesla   3
 11-50  Nike    11
        Target  18
        Tiffany 19
        Adidas  26
        Facebook    48
51-100  Ralph Lauren    54
        Apple   55
        Walmart 77
        Google  81
        Amazon  97
```

Comment: Please use df.set_index(['Category','Company']) to get the required output.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a MultiIndex instead of a `groupby()`

First create a column that bins your uploads like you proposed:

```
df = df.sort_values('Uploads',ascending=False)
df['Range'] = np.digitize(df['Uploads'],[0,11,51,100]) #bins <=10, 11-50, 50-100
#only handles up to 100, if there are values above 100 you need to expand that second list
```

Now we map the resulting values of our bin to a more descriptive string

```
df = df.sort_values('Range')
key_range = np.vectorize(lambda x: {1:'<10',2:'11-50',3:'51-100'}[x])
df['Range'] = k(df['Range'])
```

Create a multiIndex to get your desired `df`

```
df.set_index(['Range','Company'])
```

output:

```
                  Uploads
Range  Company           
<10    Tesla            3
11-50  Facebook        48
       Adidas          26
       Tiffany         19
       Target          18
       Nike            11
51-100 Amazon          97
       Google          81
       Walmart         77
       Apple           55
       Ralph           54
```